# Problems with initializing fields to null for widgets

Tags: java, swing

I was going through some codes for views and noticed the following a lot:

```
public class FooPanel extends JPanel {
   private JCheckBox checkBox = null;
   private JComboBox comboBox = null; 

   ...

   protected void initView() {
       checkBox = new JCheckBox();
       comboBox = new JComboBox();
   }
}
```

Are there any problems associated with initializing fields to null even though they are null w/o you declaring it?

One thing I saw was that 2 instances of an object are created if you initialize to null as follows:

```
public class FooPanel extends JPanel {
   private JPanel innerPanel = null;

   ...

   protected void initView() {
       add.(getInnerPanel());
   }

   private JPanel getInnerPanel() {
       if(innerPanel == null) {
           innerPanel = new JPanel();
       }

       return innerPanel;
   }
}
```

In this case, I get 2 innerPanels. Also, what is the convention? Should you write a getWidget() for each widget in a panel? I think those were generated by WindowsBuilder plugin in Eclipse.

Thanks!!

Comment: "_2 instances of an object are created if you initialize to null_" I don't believe that.

Comment: It occurred in conjunction with the getInnerPanel() method. Do you see the method causing any problems? I was debugging some code once and I saw that removing the null init for a combo box fixed an issue where there were two instances of it, one being empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Regarding assigning member values to `null`:

There aren't going to be any problems associated with assigning the value `null` to a member during declaration (or at times other than declaration). One advantage to this type of assignment is that it makes the code explicit and makes your intention very clear to anyone reading the code later. When a member variable is not assigned a value during declaration, it isn't clear whether the author intended the value to be `null` or simply forgot to write the assignment code.

### Regarding 2 `innerPanel` instances

The initial assignment to `null`, followed by assigning a value at time of need (as it is done in your code), won't cause 2 instances to be created. It's not clear from the code shown exactly how your `getInnerPanel` method is being used, but you *may be* running into a multi-threaded scenario where 2 threads may be calling `getInnerPanel` at about the same time.

In this scenario, you could end up with multiple `innerPanel` member assignments (and duplicate construction). It is possible for the first thread to check the value of `innerPanel`, find that it is currently `null` (thereby entering the associated code within the `if` condition), and then run the `JPanel` construction and assignment code. If a different thread runs the same code, at about the same time, the second thread may perform the same `innerPanel` value check, find that the value is still `null` (because the code within the `if` condition has not yet performed the construction and assignment), and enter the same construction and assignment code, resulting in multiple construction occurrences.

You could make the `innerPanel` access `synchronized`, within the `getInnerPanel` method, to prevent this from happening:

#### First Synchronization Option:

```
private synchronized JPanel getInnerPanel() {
    if(innerPanel == null) {
        innerPanel = new JPanel();
    }
    return innerPanel;
}
```

#### Second Synchronization Option:

```
private JPanel getInnerPanel() {
    synchronized(innerPanel) {
        if(innerPanel == null) {
            innerPanel = new JPanel();
        }
    }
    return innerPanel;
}
```

The second option is the better option, because it reduces the scope of the code that is `synchronized`, but not by very much. And if you expect the `getInnerPanel` method to be called many times, neither of the options shown may be the best option, because every thread that calls the method will be slowed down by the synchronization and the `null` check.

In your example, the key trade-off centers around the `innerPanel` member. If you know that the `innerPanel` will always be created or almost always created, it may be better to remove the lazy initialization (where the `JPanel` is constructed at time-of-need), simply construct the `JPanel` as part of the `innerPanel` declaration and assignment, which will also remove the need for a `null` check within the `getInnerPanel` method. The up-front `JPanel` construction also removes any need for the `null` check and the `getInnerPanel` method could simply return a reference to the `innerPanel` member.

If, on the other hand, you truly do have some panels that may or may not be constructed, depending upon need, the lazy initialization you have implemented makes perfect sense.

### Regarding a get method for each JPanel

Having a get method for each panel makes sense, if you feel like it makes the code clearer and easier to use, and especially if it is a pattern that you plan to implement across your project. That said, the associated lazy initialization and the associated `synchronized` blocks of code should be examined (based on the trade-off considerations described above) and implemented in the way that best matches the way that you believe the panels will be needed and constructed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it was cause any problems but like you said - there might've been some thread that read the value as null at a point and created one instance. I think there was some method that should've been run in a GUI thread but was not. I'll look deeper and sorry to everyone if my lack of sloc in example confused people... there is a lot to post.

Comment: Do you think you can explain to me why this occurs? I don't quite get how to read the operations such as aloan: javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=14

Comment: The "best practice" at the link you mention is making the point that member assignments to default values are unnecessary, since Java will automatically assign a default value. I believe that "best practice" is missing the point, because the goal is to write code that clearly expresses its intent. Relying on a language side-effect does not explicitly convey the intent, because it's not clear that the developer intended the default value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference whether you assign a field to `null` or leave it untouched. The two cases compile to exactly the same thing (see bottom of answer for bytecode).

As for 2 instances being created: I don't see how two would be created. If `innerPanel` hasn't been set and is `null`, a `JPanel` is constructed and stored. If it does exist, it is returned without touching anything. Whatever you do with that is your choice.

Bytecode:

```
$ cat TestNull.java
public class TestNull {
    public Object obj = null;
}
$ cat TestBlank.java
public class TestBlank {
    public Object obj;
}
$ javap -c TestNull
Compiled from "TestNull.java"
public class TestNull {
    public java.lang.Object obj;

    public TestNull();
      Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // super()
       4: aload_0
       5: aconst_null
       6: putfield      #2                  // obj = null
       9: return
}
$ javap -c TestBlank
Compiled from "TestBlank.java"
public class TestBlank {
    public java.lang.Object obj;

    public TestBlank();
      Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // super()
       4: aload_0
       5: aconst_null
       6: putfield      #2                  // obj = null
       9: return
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what this site is implying then? http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=14

Comment: @Baikol It's not saying that creates more objects; it's saying that stating the initialization explicitly when it's implied already is redundant. (e.g. "The slow turtle" is redundant because all turtles are slow and you know that anyway.) Leaving out the initialization isn't a good recommendation though, as it obscures intent. If such a field is used before being initialized, it will sometimes be confusing as you'd wonder how it was set to null. It will normally take a moment to notice that the field is implicitly null by the blank definition, and this kind of confusion should be avoided.